# Particular experience with using different MCUs from different vendors

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, platform, nxp-microcontroller

I've recently had an interview for an embedded C software position where the interviewer asked which type of Microcontrollers I am most familiar with - from TI, NXP, STMicroelectronics etc.?

I mentioned that I have used NXP MCUs quite a bit in the past. They then asked if I have any experience with TI chips.

I struggle a bit to understand why it's so important to know if one has experince with a particular MCU from a particular vendor.

When we're developing applications in embedded C (or C++), aren't we mostly abstracted from the platform-specific stuff? Unless we are writing bootloaders from scratch and of course drivers.Changing platforms shouldn't be a major issue right?

What are other major benefits of someone being used to working with MCUs from one particular vendor? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the whole there is no benefit other than maybe using any proprietary tool set that the manufacture may provide unless you need to delve into using assembly language.

Comment: "*Unless we are writing bootloaders from scratch and of course drivers*" - but it is the most common case for the embedded MCU developer - to develop bare metal. Even when developing in C, you are still dealing with low - level platform specific stuff.. But I guess they are interested to know how steep the learning curve would be. The vendors differ in the clarity and availability of documentation, tools and ecosystem. But I agree, that once you are familiar with 3-4 of them, there won't be any problem to master other ten.

Comment: @EugeneSh. agreed! But from my experience - only very bright individuals easily learn new stuff, most struggle and it takes a very long time to be familiar with new hardware. So, during the interview, if I see that particular person is not in that top 1% (and it is OK for the role), I ask this question.

Comment: @ChrisBD Thanks for your replies. I guess if the Vendor provides specific libraries and SDK etc. that one has used before is a plus also.

Comment: "_I struggle a bit to understand why it's so important to know if one has experience with a particular MCU from a particular vendor._" - did you tell them that?  They may have explained it and you could have discussed that.

Comment: @Clifford :) Probably the best reply I could've used yes

Comment: "_aren't we mostly abstracted from the platform-specific stuff?_" - Well it is true that you would do well in most cases to use an abstraction, but someone has to implement that abstraction - perhaps they want someone who can do that.  Perhaps their existing implementations don't use an abstraction layer - if you were to discuss that with them they might be interested in your approach.

Comment: _"Changing platforms shouldn't be a major issue right?"_.  Well you might be exploiting a feature specific to a particular MCU that does not necessarily lend itself to an abstraction, or for which an abstraction might not meet real-time timing constraints, or memory footprint constraints.  A third-party generalised abstraction will likely be larger and slower than an in-house application/MCU specific solution.  What you should perhaps have addressed is the range of MCUs you have worked with, how quickly you have got up to speed with each, and how proficient you are with datasheets.

Comment: Either way, I am commenting not answering, because this is clearly "opinion based" so off topic.

Comment: C provides abstraction over code generation, addressing, calling conventions/ABI and so on. But it doesn't provide abstraction of the hardware peripherals. You have to write that yourself (or peek at the fugly code given to you by the MCU vendor and then write it yourself based on that).

Comment: I think it mattered more back in the days (2000s) when you had "the Motorola camp", "the 8051 camp", "the PIC camp" and so on. A leftover from the 1990s when most MCUs were still coded in assembler.

Comment: @Clifford Is it really opinion-based though - some 3-4 embedded veteran programmers have left various sensible comments above and I think we all agree of everything said. Meaning it isn't really subjective. It might be a bit of a broad topic however.

Comment: @Lundin  I agree that there are objective principles, but the final question - "_What are other major benefits of someone being used to working with MCUs from one particular vendor?_" is more subjective.  Might be a benefit in some circumstances, or you might value more general experience and adaptability.  For a short term contract, you might want someone who has very specific experience, for a perm you would perhaps favour more long term skills.

Comment: It can be extremely expensive for a company to change from one chip or vendor to another.   A corporation will pay for support, sometimes quantities that would be quantities that are on par with half your salary or a while years salary as a reference.  This gives them instant and quality support even folks that may drive or fly to your site.  Access to their full suite of tools, on and on.  Often, these days, the same things we can download for free.

Comment: Products take years to develop, and ideally stay on the market for a long time.  You do product support for a while and then at some point start on another.  After one or two or a dozen products of 10-20+ years, that relationship with that vendor is like a marriage.  Seems trivial to just divorce and remarry someone whenever you like right? Take on the next persons kids and abandon the others?  Aint no thing right?  its not.  nor are relationships with the suppliers nor the relationship and support contracts with the vendors.

Comment: Companies will use a higher price, lower performance product from their comfortable vendor vs new vendors.  Part of this is also deparments and office politics.  A particular manager with a particular power may hold that vendor until they retire or move onto a higher position, some new up and comer, hot shot, thinks they are going to make the company better are where you may see a new marriage if you will, and that eitther goes down in flames on the first product or struggles for a while or you go through a sampling of vendors.

Comment: some companies are about price, but often they are about the lowest cost and I would venture a guess lowest quality products, with little to no support, get it built get it out, very high volume production with an above average yield loss and a noticable return rate or failure in the field.  the cost per unit, IF you can keep the NRE down (Changing vendors can drive up nre if you switch every time)(although if you use free tools...you get an employee for a year for free).   that or startups would do this.

Comment: since, today, there are so many very cheap eval boards or you can make your own pcb and solder a part down for a few bucks.  if you want to be in this business you should while you search, spend your nights and weekends downloading the tools and playing with them even without hardware, and then get a mixture of hardware, so that you can 1) I have messed iwth abc, xyz, 123... 2) Yes I used their tool and this part (remember the numbers if you can, some detail), what did you do with it. I paired it with a esp8266 to make a detector to see if my garage door was left open. dog feeder, etc...

Comment: most vendors have the old sdk and the new sdk, just how that works.  learn both per vendor.   and then IMO learn the low level, most of their libraries are very scary if you look behind the curtain. will your boss really care if you cost the company a mllion bucks because you didnt test the library you downloaded?  instead of actually owning it and making sure it was good enough quality?  can you debug the difference between a chip bug, a compiler bug and a pcb bug?  not always required for the job, but makes you more valuable if you can.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very important, though in case you are familiar with one particular microcontroller, you can "hit the ground running" so to speak. Meaning it is often a merit during employment, more so than a hard requirement. In the ARM era, this is even less important and it's more about which tool chains you are used with.

And naturally, experienced programmers pick up new tool chains and new microcontrollers much faster than beginners who have no idea how things are usually done. So IMO past microcontroller experience is more relevant when hiring junior devs. For example you don't want to make the mistake of hiring someone who has only used Arduino (not really a merit) and then toss them into a bare metal MSP430 project. I would imagine that your interviewer has similar thoughts.

> When we're developing applications in embedded C (or C++), aren't we mostly abstracted from the platform-specific stuff?

Not really, since bare metal/RTOS microcontroller applications are very low level and close to the hardware. Having experience with various oddities and hardware peripherals saves time. A whole lot of embedded programming isn't related to C.

RL anecdote from today: I've spent my whole day troubleshooting why a ATSAM MCU wouldn't start without the debugger attached. Having ruled out the watchdog, BOD, reset pin, the ICD itself, supply voltage and using a RAM build by mistake, experience from using Cortex M eventually sent me digging into the CRT and I concluded that it was an issue with wrong linkage of the whole vector table. Nasty problem that took me 5 hours to solve including poking support.

A beginner who barely knows what a vector table is wouldn't even know where to start troubleshooting something like this. They would perhaps sit and stare into the C code indeed, though nothing of this problem was the slightest related to C programming. I had to read a bit of assembler, though most of the troubleshooting involved poking around with an oscilloscope and an ICD, as well as viewing the board in the PCB CAD. All part of an embedded programmers job.